# Windows 8 Localizations in app manifest

Tags: localization, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I need to localize some data in application manifest (like name, description, splashscreen images etc.) According to documentation these data can be provided as resources but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you follow a naming convention in your folder hierarchy.  Here's a link that explains [how to name properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965372.aspx).  There is another helpful "how to" article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967759.aspx) and two quickstarts to walk you through it in [Javascript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh943060.aspx) and [XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965329(v=win.10).aspx).

Specifically, look through the quickstarts (using the above links) for the step-by-step walkthrough.  It is slightly different in JavaScript vs. XAML, but the overall steps are:

1. Set your default language in the Visual Studio project properties.
2. Create a folder in your project to hold all of the different resource files (one for each language).  This will keep your project neat and organized.
3. Right-click on this folder and select "Add New Item" to add a resource file for a language.  This file may be a .resx, .resw, .resjson - see the quickstarts for the specifics, based on what language you are coding in.
4. Add the items that you want to translate in your resources file.  Again, see the quickstarts for specifics.
5. Associate your controls with resources and add string resource identifiers to your code.

Let me know if the quickstarts don't help.

Comment: Ok, thanks but i still don't know how to localize for example application's name

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a localized resource (e.g. Strings/en/Resources.resw) with key "Appname" and value "My App Title"
2. Add a second localized resource (e.g. Strings/de/Resources.resw) with key "Appname" and value "My German App Title"
3. Edit you "App Manifest" and enter "ms-resource:Appname" in the "Display name" field (Application UI)
4. Edit you "App Manifest" and enter "ms-resource:Appname" in the "Package display name" field (Packaging)

Note: Before you do all that, you should [register the app name](https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-US/Developer/Catalog/AddProductName/) in the Windows Store Dashboard.